# Facing Looping Issue in Java Spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, websphere-8, jsessionid

I have developed Spring webflow applications, execution will complete in 5 steps.
Sometime I am facing looping issue,i.e. After second or third step I am landing on first step on same session.
for example :

1. Step Start url : **`temp/spring/webflow?flowExecutionSnapshotId=e1s1`**
2. Step Url : **`temp/spring/webflow?flowExecutionSnapshotId=e1s2`**
3. Step Url : **`temp/spring/webflow?flowExecutionSnapshotId=e1s3`**

Once execution of `#3` completed it will load `#1` url again

I am using WebSphere 8 Server

added more points :
I check for `JSESSIOID` i could see it is getting updated. 
I am having only one ear but installed two node of server which is balanced by load balancer to serve incoming request. 
is there any possibility because of 2 nodes `JSESSIOID` is reset ?
or any other issue which cause flow reset issue.

Comment: No session timeout, correct? Anything logged in SystemOut.log? Is it always on a specific state? Can you show your flow-xml states?

Comment: yes On same session, There is nothing in SystemOut.log,  Request is initiated some time and some time it works, request is initiated from second and some time from third step.  I am using subflow where Step 2 and Step 3 is part of Subflow....  I have scan code and Webflow but there is nothing which is responsible to redirect request to Start flow  Ok I will upload webflow.xml files soon

Comment: One more observation : During looping issue after flow reset to start state value of flowExecutionSnapshotId is e1s1 insted of e2s1 or other values on same session.